# Setting up a variable in a SQL IF-ELSE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following statement:

```
IF (SELECT IntId 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Name = 'Jon') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT IntId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not an id'
END
```

The IntId is the PK of the table and I want to see if it exists for the `Name = Jon` but it is out of scope so how do I get it to print?

Comment: What happens when you inevitably have more than 1 person called Jon?

Comment: Yes sorry that was bad psuedo code their as I changed the exactness of what I put on SO but the name is an AK in the database for this example, but that is a valid point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways you might be able to accomplish this.

**Using a variable**

```
DECLARE @IntId int;

SET @IntId = (
    /* I added a TOP 1, in case your query returns more
    than one row. If it does return more than 1 row, you're
    looking at looping data to a print statement, and that's
    a different question. */

    SELECT TOP 1 IntId
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Name = 'Jon'
    ORDER BY IntId
)

IF @IntId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @IntId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not an id'
END
```

**IF EXISTS, select something**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'Jon')
BEGIN
    SELECT IntId FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'Jon'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not an id'
END
```

Comment: I honestly disagree with dumping a `TOP 1` in that subquery, as it simply hides the problem. If you *are* going to use a `TOP 1` at least put an `ORDER BY` there so that it doesn't return an arbitrary value.

Comment: @Larnu I agree. That's why I put a comment there. Maybe the OP just wants the top values, so it's there as an example. The OP question was about getting something into a PRINT statement, which that achieves.

Comment: That doesn't change my point that there should be an `ORDER BY` for consistent results though. Either remove the `TOP` or add the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: You're correct. I updated my answer. The point of my answer was more to provide a working example of passing a variable value to print. That was short-sited on my part to not include the ORDER BY. Stu actually provides a better overall answer than mine, anyways.

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'Jon') IS NOT NULL` provides the blessing "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'." Since `exists` returns a [`boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2019#boolean-data-type) result which cannot be `null` there isn't much need to check for `null`. Aside: Performing two queries to get one result isn't likely to improve performance in this case.

Comment: Copy paste got me

Answer (score 3):

What you *could do* in this scenario if using SQL Server 2017+ is use *string_agg* which would give you all ID values if there's duplicates:

```
declare @id varchar(max);
select @id=String_Agg(IntId, ',')
from MyTable
where [Name] = 'jon';

print isnull(@id, 'not an id');
```

Comment: An alternative is to replace the `case` with `Coalesce( @id, 'not an id' )`.

Comment: Yes that woud be even more compact 

Answer (score 1):

You have two option. Repeat that select again which is not recommended because of performance issue. and the second it to store in a variable.

```
Declare @IntId int
SELECT @IntId = IntId 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Name = 'Jon'

IF (@IntId) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @IntId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not an id'
END
```